# General solution of 3d wave equation as a superposition of plane/spherical waves

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light

Is the general solution to the 3d wave equation a superposition of plane/spherical waves? Can this be shown?

Comment: Boundary conditions are important. For instance, linear functions can also be a solution

Comment: All you need can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it using Fourier transforms. If you have never seen them, the following could be a bit confusing. However, basically what one can do is write your unknown function as a infinite sum of waves with a spatial frequency $k$, solve it for each value of $k$ and then go sum it back to the original function. This procedure, as the wave equation is relatively easy to solve for a single wave, often really helps!

If you have the wave equation

$${\partial^2 y \over \partial t^2} = c \nabla ^2 y$$

where $\nabla^2={\partial^2  \over \partial x^2}+{\partial^2 \over \partial y^2}+{\partial^2 \over \partial z^2}$

you can use a Fourier transform to attempt solving it, i.e. a sort of infinite sum of plane waves.

In case you don't know Fourier transforms, briefly you can write every function in 3D $y(\textbf{r}=(x, y, z))$ (provided they satisfy some very general conditions) as a sum of plane waves of the form $e^{i\textbf{k}\cdot\textbf{r}}$, with $\textbf{k}=(k_x, k_y, k_z)$, as

$$y(\textbf{r}) = A \int \hat{y}(\textbf{k}) e^{i\textbf{k}\cdot\textbf{r}}d\textbf{k}$$

where $A$ is a constant and $\hat{y}(\textbf{k})$ is the so called Fourier transform and represents the continous coefficients of the series.

By substituting this expression in the wave equation we get an equation for $\hat{y}(\textbf{k})$ which is

$${\partial^2 \hat{y}(\textbf{k}) \over \partial t^2} = -c k^2 \hat{y}(\textbf{k})$$

To prove it, just plug the expression I wrote up there in the wave equation and use the fact that $i^2=-1$ and ${\partial e^{i\textbf{k}\cdot\textbf{r}} \over \partial x} = i k_x e^{i\textbf{k}\cdot\textbf{r}}$ and similar.

This equations is often easier to solve (it is very close the equation for a harmonic oscillator) but still requires the boundary conditions for $y$ to be completely solvable. Once it is solved, using the expression for $y(\textbf{r})$, you can "invert" the Fourier transform to get the solution of your original functions.

You could do the same for spherical waves by finding an appropriate expression for $\nabla$ and for the Fourier transform.

Comment: It's actually exactly the conditions that a 3-dimensional function has to satisfy for it to be able to be decomposed into plane waves and that proof that it can that I'm after. I can see that this if true for the 1-dimensional case where one simply considers sinusoids rather than plane waves but I don't see why this is necessarily true for the 3-d case with plane waves.

Comment: Well, the conditions for which the Fourier Transform works are very general (the integral of its squared value over the domain must converge and similar things). For almost all "normal" functions it will be possible to write a FT. However, as the FT is a *infinite* sum of waves the result can also NOT be of "sinusoidal" shape (or rather, it can be a-periodic), unlike in the Fourier series which requires periodicity. As an example, a function $f=c$ where c is a constant does solve the wave equation without being a wave. If you add boundary conditions, your question might have a better answer.

Comment: Anyway as a starting point I would look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform

Comment: You're right, I hadn't thought enough about the 3 dimensional Fourier transform. It's really very general! If you can integrate the function it everywhere there's nothing stopping you from finding the Fourier coefficients.

Comment: Although keep in mind that the final solution is not always periodic/wave-like although it can be decomposed in plane waves ;)